# A finite measure space is separable if and only if its induced $L_1$ space is separable

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

I'm reading about [symmetric difference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Symmetric_difference_on_measure_spaces) on a $\sigma$-finite measure space from Wikipedia. Below is my try to prove a statement mentioned in this article.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a separable Banach space. We define a [pseudometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Symmetric_difference_on_measure_spaces) $d_{\mu}(A, B) := \mu(A \triangle B)$ on $\mathcal A$. Then $d_\mu$ becomes a metric when $\mathcal A$ is considered modulo the equivalence relation $A \sim B \iff \mu(A \triangle B) = 0$. Let $L_1 := L_{1}(\Omega, \mu, E)$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ be its canonical norm.

> **Theorem:** $d_\mu$ is separable if and only if $\|\cdot\|_1$ is separable.

Could you please have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** Let $S := S(\Omega, \mu, E)$ be the space of simple functions and $D$ a countable dense subset of $E$.

$\implies$ Assume $d_\mu$ is separable and $\mathcal D$ a countable dense subset of $\mathcal A$. Because $S$ is dense in $L_1$. It suffices to show that $S$ is separable. Let
$$
S_1 := \left \{ \sum_{i=1}^m a_i 1_{A_i} \,\middle\vert\, m \in\mathbb N^*; a_1, \ldots, a_m \in D; A_1, \ldots,  A_m \in \mathcal D \right \}.
$$

Then $S_1 \subset S$ is countable. Let's prove that $S_1$ is dense $S$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$ and $f=\sum_{i=1}^m x_i 1_{B_i} \in S$ such that $(x_i)_{i=1}^m \subset E$ is pairwise different and $(B_i)_{i=1}^m \subset \mathcal A$ is pairwise disjoint.
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left \| f - \sum_{i=1}^m a_i 1_{A_i} \right \|_1 &\le \sum_{i=1}^m \left \|  x_i 1_{B_i} -  a_i 1_{A_i} \right \|_1 \\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^m \|(x_i-a_i) 1_{A_i}\|_1 + \|x_i (1_{B_i} - 1_{A_i})\|_1 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m |x_i-a_i| \mu(A_i) + |x_i| d_\mu (A_i, B_i) \\
\end{align}
$$

- There are $A_i \in \mathcal D$ such that $d_{\mu}(A_i, B_i) \max_j |x_j| \le \frac{\varepsilon}{2m}$.
- There are $a_i \in D$ such that $|x_i-a_i| \mu(A_i)< \frac{\varepsilon}{2m}$.

Then
$$
\left \| f - \sum_{i=1}^m a_i 1_{A_i} \right \|_1 \le \varepsilon.
$$

$\impliedby$ Assume $\|\cdot\|_1$ is separable. Fix some $a \in E \setminus \{0\}$. A subset of a separable metric space is separable, so $\{ a1_A \mid A \in \mathcal A\}$ is separable. Let $S_2$ be a countable dense subset of $\{ a1_A \mid A \in \mathcal A\}$. Let $\mathcal D := \{A \in \mathcal A \mid a1_A \in S_2\}$. Let's prove that $\mathcal D$ is dense in $\mathcal A$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$ and $A \in \mathcal A$. There is $B \in \mathcal D$ such that
$$
\|a1_A -a1_B\|_1 = |a| d_\mu(A, B) = |a| \mu(A \triangle B) < \varepsilon |a|.
$$

This means there is $B \in \mathcal D$ such that $\mu(A \triangle B) < \varepsilon$. This completes the proof.

Comment: The proof seems fine, but may I ask why in the last of the second part you considered $\{a1_A : A \in \mathcal{A} \}$ the collection of scaled characteristic functions instead of just characteristic functions?

Comment: @ムータンーオ It's because the characteristic functions are *real*-valued, not $E$-valued.

Comment: I see, have to say this $E$ being a Banach space makes it slightly confusing. I automatically treat $E$ as $\mathbb{R}$ and $D$ as $\mathbb{Q}$. I think it would be better to stress where the finiteness of $\mu$ is used, in particular the choice of $a_i$ in the first part, and $\{ a1_A  : A \in \mathcal{A}\} \subset L^1$ in the second part.